# Meaning of " to be dizzying in"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, context

There is a text in my english book that talks about the wetlands from Brazil and there is a sentence that goes like this: "(...) life is dizzying in its abundance, variety and beauty."

I have already searched for the meaning of this word, and I found that it means "very fast and confusing" according to Cambridge dictionary, and according to Merriam Webster Dictionary :" having a whirling sensation in the head with a tendency to fall."

But I still do not understand what this expression means inside the text. I would be happy if you guys could give me a hand.

Comment: Do you know the word "dizzy" (_tonto_)? I think this question is better suited for [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to know the meaning of this word inside the text.

Comment: So abundant and beautiful that you get dizzy... There's no hidden meaning here.

Comment: Sadly, 'dizzy in' is not a multi-word verb. At least, not yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's not **dizzying in** that you should be looking at, since **in its abundance, variety and beauty** is an [adjective phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) modifying **life**.

You could re-position the adjective phrase to directly after **life**:

**Life**, *in its abundance, variety and beauty*, **is dizzying**.

With dizzying having exactly its dictionary meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In this context you could read that line as "the abundance, variety and beauty of life makes it a dizzying experience".